# Why do tests in derived classes rerun the parent class tests?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, nosetests

When there is significant overlap in test setup, it can keep things DRY to use inheritance.  But this causes issues with unnecessary duplication of test execution:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class TestPotato(TestCase):
    def test_in_parent(self):
        print 'in parent'

class TestSpud(TestPotato):
    def test_in_child(self):
        print 'in child'
```

Testing this module runs the `test_in_parent` twice.

```
$ python -m unittest example
in parent
.in child
.in parent
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why?  Is this by design? Can it be disabled by configuring the test runner in a certain way?

I can workaround the issue by moving setup into a non-discovered class, and then use multiple inheritence, but it seems a bit hacky and unnecessary.

*note:* Same problem occurs in other runners such as nose (`nosetests -s example.py`) and pytest (`py.test example.py`)

Comment: Because they inherit the test methods of their parents, so when `unittest` looks through their `dir` (or `__dict__` or whatever it does) for methods starting `test_` it finds the inherited ones, too. I don't think solving this requires *multiple* inheritance; abstract what both need to a third, undiscoverable class with no `test_` methods and have them both inherit it.

Comment: Introspecting a subclass that has a parent class that contains methods prefixed by test will show the subclass with those methods.  This is python OOP.  I don't think moving setup methods to mixin or as a separate base class seems hacky at all, and is maybe DRYer

Comment: Seems like a great use case for mixins for different "groups" of tests to dynamically create the exact test you need...tree-inheritance doesn't look like the right model here.

Comment: The answer seems to be "Python OOP is broken - but OOP is bad anyway".  I agree that Python OOP is broken, but OOP is extremely useful in many cases.  Composition is good also, but OOP is not bad, it is very useful in some cases.  I need all test cases to have some common variables that are set in a base class so that each class does not have a copy of of those variables that point to classes I need in all test cases - that is one point of OOP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test runners look up of all methods starting with `test`. Inherited methods are present in child class - therefore they are detected as tests to run.
To avoid that you should extract common code in parent class and do not inherit any actual tests.

```
from unittest import TestCase

class PotatoTestTemplate(TestCase):
    def setUp():
        pass

class PotatoTest1(PotatoTestTemplate):
    def test1(self):
        pass

class PotatoTest2(PotatoTestTemplate):
    def test1(self):
        pass
```

Comment: I have settled on a pattern similar to this - instead of the `PotatoTestTemplate` I use a `PotatoSetup(object)`.  It's not a `TestCase`, it's more like a mixin.  Then I use `PotatoTest(PotatoSetup, TestCase)` and `SpudTest(PotatoSetup, TestCase)` with extra setup in either test if I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround i have seen people use is that nested classes wont get run as part of nosetests e.g.

```
from unittest import TestCase
class NotTested:
    class TestPotato(TestCase):
        def test_in_parent(self):
            print 'in parent'

class TestSpud(NotTested.TestPotato):
    def test_in_child(self):
        print 'in child'
```

A workaround I unsuccessfully tried was to use multiple inheritance so the TestPotato class extends object  and TestSpud does extend from TestCase and TestPotato
e.g.

```
from unittest import TestCase

class TestPotato(object):
    def test_in_parent(self): 
        # still gets ran twice because
        # nosetests runs anything that starts with test_* :(
         print 'in parent'

class TestSpud(TestCase, TestPotato):
    def test_in_child(self):
        print 'in child'
```

But this actually didn't work for me, i wish it did because you wouldn't  need the added nesting of code... but it looks like using [multiple inheritance is bad anyway](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201210/multiple_inheritance_is_hard.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the test setUp from a different test class is all you need, you could do this:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class TestPotato(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print('fixtures here')

    def test_in_parent(self):
        print 'in parent'


class TestSpud(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        TestPotato.setUp(self)

    def test_in_child(self):
        print 'in child'
```