# With Python unittest OOP base & child class, when executed the base class is observed to run the constructor & test_ method more times than expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-unittest

**Technical areas:**

- Python Programming
- Python OOP
- Python unittest

---

**Description:**

With Python OOP (unittest scenario), I am a little confused.

I have a base/parent class.  I run it and see the constructor called once and a method in the class called once as expected.

```
import unittest
import datetime


class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    All test classes should inherit this to get:  self.config
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        print('TestBase.__init__(): now=[' + self.now + ']', flush=True)

    def test_canary_base(self):
        """
        A test that is known good and will always pass
        """
        print("TestBase.test_canary_base()", flush=True)
```

---

Now I create a child class derived from the base/parent class and I run it.

```
import datetime
from test.test_base import TestBase


class TestChild(TestBase):
    """
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestChild, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        print('TestChild.__init__(): now=[' + self.now + ']')

    def test_canary_child(self):
        """
        A test that is known good and will always pass
        """
        print("TestChild.test_canary_child()", flush=True)
```

I see the **base/parent class constructor called three times** and a **test_** method in the base/parent class called **twice**.  This is unexpected.

---

Additionally, I see the **child constructor called twice** and a **test_** method in the class called once.

Why is the derived class constructor called twice?

---

Why, in both the base/parent class and the child class are the constructor and test_ method not called just once?

---

I have a git repo from which actual code can be cloned and run locally to demonstrate the problem (will commit/push in a moment).

**https://github.com/devlocalca/python-unittest-oop**

---

**To reproduce:**

1. clone the git repo
2. setup IDE project
3. run the base/parent class:  test/test_base.py
4. observe the output

You will see the following output:

```
TestBase.__init__(): now=[2023-11-14 14:32:52.052573]
TestBase.test_canary_base()
```

now run the child class:
test/test_child.py

You will see the following output (that I would not expect):

```
TestBase.__init__(): now=[2023-11-14 14:26:02.137958]
TestBase.__init__(): now=[2023-11-14 14:26:02.137958]
TestChild.__init__(): now=[2023-11-14 14:26:02.137958]
TestBase.__init__(): now=[2023-11-14 14:26:02.137958]
TestChild.__init__(): now=[2023-11-14 14:26:02.137958]
TestBase.test_canary_base()
TestBase.test_canary_base()
TestChild.test_canary_child()
```

---

now run a **test_grandchild.py** that inherits from **test_child.py**

---

How would this be fixed so that I would see the expected output of the base/parent constructor and **test_** method called only once (along with the child class being called only once).

I believe a working example would help me explore this issue.

Comment: `TestChild` has two test methods: `test_canary_child` (defined in the child class), and `test_canary_base` (inherited from the parent class). The test framework runs both of those methods, and for each method it creates a new instance of `TestChild` (per the docs: *"A new TestCase instance is created as a unique test fixture used to execute each individual test method."*, https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) So you would expect to see `TestChild.__init__()` twice in the output.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503377/why-do-tests-in-derived-classes-rerun-the-parent-class-tests

Comment: @slothrop - this is very undesirable behavior - that for each test_ method it would instantiate a new class just to run that one method.  

I only want one instance of the class instantiated, and for all test_ methods to be invoked when the test is run.

I would never expect that for each test_ method in a class that a new class would be instantiated.  It would be good to know who thought of this and who can change it.

Comment: @slothrop As a programmer, I want to control when a class is instantiated and how many instances there are.  This is quite unbelievable.

When a child derives from a base class, there should be one class instantiated, only one and all methods in the hiearchy become part of the one class (all variables and all methods are part of a singular class).

Comment: @slothrop - it is still not explained why the base class constructor is called three times, if only two classes are instantiated.  Where does the third call to the base class constructor come from?

Also test_canary_base() is called twice.  This is unexpected, even if two classes are instantiated.  I would expect it to only be called once.  

The derived class has two methods: test_canary_base(), test_canary_child() and so if a class is instantiated for each test, then only two classes would be instantiated, and each of those methods would only be called once.  So I still do not understand

Comment: You can't expect that classes work the same when `unittest` is in control. It has its own rules which @slothrop has explained above. You never show that you instantiate these classes (which is entirely correct), so it is `unittest` alone which handles that. `unittest` makes three instances of classes, one for each method it calls.

Comment: @user10664542 *"it is still not explained why the base class constructor is called three times, if only two classes are instantiated"* Fair point, I also didn't fully solve this in my earlier comment. Note that in `test_child.py`, you do `from test.test_base import TestBase`. So the namespace of the `test_child` module contains two test classes: `TestBase` and `TestChild`. When you run the tests for that module, the tests from both test classes are run: `TestBase` has 1 test method and `TestChild` has 2, so there are 3 class instantiations in total.

Comment: You can change that by replacing `from test.test_base import TestBase` with `import test.test_base`, and changing the class declaration to `class TestChild(test.test_base.TestBase):`. That way, the namespace of the `test_child` module contains only the `TestChild` class, so only the two tests in that class are run.

Comment: Also I recommend never writing an `__init__()` method for any test classes. I would expect to write `setUp()` and `tearDown()` when needed.

Comment: Another question that may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58870032/how-do-i-keep-the-same-class-instance-in-unit-test